# How to Fill Graph with Google Visualization AreaChart when logScale is set to false

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Please consider the following set-up:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Num1', 'Perc1'],
      [{v:0, f:'1 jan. 2014'}, {v:1000, f:'1.000'}, {v:2.15, f:'2,15%'}],
      [{v:1, f:'1 feb. 2014'}, {v:1170, f:'1.170'}, {v:6.5, f:'6,4%'}],
      [{v:2, f:'1 mrt. 2014'}, {v:1120, f:'1.120'}, {v:21, f:'21,00%'}],
      [{v:3, f:'1 apr. 2014'}, {v:1030, f:'1.030'}, {v:0.99, f:'0,99%'}]
    ]);

var options = {
  title: '',
  legend: 'none',
  fontSize: 11,
  chartArea: {
    left:40,
    top:10,
    width:'90%',
    height:'70%'
  },
  hAxis: {
    baseline: {
      baselineColor:'transparent'
    },
    gridlines: {
      count:2,
      color:'transparent'
    },
    textStyle: {
      color:'#aaa'
    },
    ticks :[{v: 0, f: '1 jan. 2014'}, {v: 3, f: '1 apr. 2014'}]
  },
  vAxis: {
    baseline: {
      baselineColor:'#ccc'
    },
    gridlines: {
      color:'#ddd',
      count:3
    },
    textStyle: {
      color:'#aaa'
    }
  },
  vAxes:{
    0:{
      logScale:false
    },
    1:{
      logScale:false,
      format: '#,##%'
    }
  },
  series:{
    0:{
      targetAxisIndex: 0,
      areaOpacity: 0.2,
      color: 'orange'
    },
    1:{
      targetAxisIndex: 1,
      areaOpacity:0.2,
      color: 'green'
    }
  },
  focusTarget: 'category',
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  },
  pointSize: 5,
  backgroundColor:
  {
   fill: 'transparent',
   stroke: '#ddd',
   strokeWidth: 1,
  }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Now apparently the graph's fill doesn't work because logScale is set to false, by setting it to true and providing it with min/maxvalues it fills, but it messes up my vertical axes and gridlines. How do i fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/5tzFC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specified the `baselineColor` option incorrectly; it is not a sub-option of `baseline`.  `baseline` expects to take a number, and when you pass it an object, the chart doesn't know what to do with it, so it removes the baseline entirely.  Setting the `logScale` option to `true` apparently forces a baseline whether you specify one or not.  Since the AreaCharts fill the area between the data line and the baseline, this is why you get no fill normally.  Correct the way in which you specify the `baselineColor` option and it should work just fine:

```
vAxis: {
    baselineColor: '#ccc',
    gridlines: {
        color: '#ddd',
        count: 3
    },
    textStyle: {
        color: '#aaa'
    }
}
```

Incidentally, the same syntax applies to the `hAxis.baselineColor` option as well:

```
hAxis: {
    baselineColor: 'transparent',
    gridlines: {
        count: 2,
        color: 'transparent'
    },
    textStyle: {
        color: '#aaa'
    },
    ticks: [{v: 0, f: '1 jan. 2014'}, {v: 3, f: '1 apr. 2014'}]
}
```

Comment: Can't believe i overlooked that. Thanks.